# how to limit the number of times Vaadin 14 tries to send heartbeat requests

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

We have a Vaadin 14 (Flow) application which is fronted by an Apache reverse proxy that integrates with [Gluu](https://www.gluu.org/) for authentication using OpenID (mod_auth_openidc).

This is generally working fine, except when users leave their browser open with the application idle for a long time, until the max session time of the OpenID session is reached.  The problem is, at that point the Vaadin client keeps trying to send heartbeat requests.  This, in combination with [this mod_auth_openidc issue](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/issues/331), results in state cookies piling up and reaching a limit so that the user has to close her browser before being able to re-login.

I've tried various things (unsuccessfully) in order to get the server to instruct the browser to visit a logout URL when a heartbeat request is received after session timeout (in combination with `vaadin.closeIdleSessions=true`), but even if it worked it wouldn't be a solution for other browser tabs that may also be open at that time and sending heartbeat requests.

What we really want is to limit the number of times the Vaadin client retries to send the heartbeat requests (say max 3 times) and then just stop sending requests (maybe display a message to re-login).

Is this possible in any way?  The current workaround is to disable the heartbeats completely, but this doesn't seem ideal (Vaadin won't detect idle UIs).

Answer (score 1):

The UI instance has a `ReconnectDialogConfiguration` which includes  `reconnectAttempts` property to control how many times to re-try requests (including heartbeat requests).  Default seems to be 10000.

In Vaadin 14 (LTS) this can be set using [PageConfigurator](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-bootstrap.html#pageconfigurator).

In Vaadin 18 (latest release) this is done using [AppShellConfigurator](https://vaadin.com/docs/v18/flow/advanced/tutorial-modifying-the-bootstrap-page.html#application-shell-configurator)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the heartbeats is the way to go. If you need something more nuanced than that, you'll need to make a change (maybe add a configuration option) in how Heartbeats work in Vaadin. Creating a ticket in GitHub could be a good place to start.

Comment: When heartbeats are disabled, are other UI instances at least cleaned up when the other browser tabs are closed?  I'm a bit in doubt about whether they are used to detect idle UIs (only sending heartbeats) or closed tabs (not sending heartbeats or requests).  If closed tabs don't get detected, it doesn't seem acceptable, but I hope the browser unload  event is sent to the server and used as well for this.

Comment: I found out myself by going through the code on GitHub (to see what needed to be changed) that this already exists (at least configurable in code) - see my own answer.

Comment: The other UI instances are cleaned up once the session times out.